# OperationalError: (2019, ""Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: C:\\mysql\\\\share\\charsets\\)"")

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows, mariadb

I configured my Django database setting in settings.py with:

```
'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
```

All columns and tables are set to utf8mb4.

I want this encoding so I can store emojis like:

When I start my script on Mac or Linux, it works fine, but on Windows, I get:

```
    <module>    C:\Users\Josh\Documents\mysite\myproj\scripts\crawler.py    154     
    __getitem__ C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py 295     
    __iter__    C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py 256     
    _fetch_all  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py 1087        
    __iter__    C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py 54      
    execute_sql C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py  833     
    cursor  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py   231     
    _cursor C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py   204     
    ensure_connection   C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py   199     
    __exit__    C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py    94      
    ensure_connection   C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py   199     
    connect C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py   171     
    get_new_connection  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py  263     
    Connect c:\users\josh\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-iz3bc1\MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\MySQLdb\__init__.py 81      
    __init__    c:\users\josh\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-iz3bc1\MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\MySQLdb\connections.py  221     
    set_character_set   c:\users\josh\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-iz3bc1\MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\MySQLdb\connections.py  312     
"OperationalError: (2019, ""Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: C:\\mysql\\\\share\\charsets\\)"")"
```

The line of code it throws the exception on is:

```
Object.objects.filter(last_scraped__isnull=True)[0]
```

Versions:

Python 2.7

Database: MariaDB 5.5

Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Does it just happen when you run `manage.py`?

Comment: Try to use standard 'utf8'- it covers nearly all symbols.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov No, this is being ran by Apache on a CentOS server.

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky Really? Do you know how many iPhone emojis it covers and doesn't?

Comment: try to clean your DB(or create a clean db) on windows and use `utf8` instead

Comment: @HaifengZhang There is no database on Windows. 1 database and it's on the server. utf8 only stores 3 bytes. I don't think it will store the 4 emjois in the question, will it?

Comment: @User, really I've never met problem with them, may be I use some other subset of emojis.

Comment: Please share with us `import sys; print sys.defaultencoding()` outputs. Another point is all module and services required same `encoding pattern`(for protect char byte positions). Never an `OS` support emotional encodings(machines is insensitive) but call(read) with any encodings style. You already know "which column include a emotional characters" encode returned values with `your_choice` encodings.

Comment: @User, no problem: http://imgur.com/JZ8O3G2

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky Did those 4 fit into utf8?

Comment: @dsgdfg Do you want that output on the server where Django is running or on the Windows machine where the script is running?

Comment: Okay, change brief style to `Bilal` ... You got already a cursor (djongo already use it) and add an another cursor with external pattern(utf8mb4) , **sorry you can't do it** what is other current procedures status ? Can't change `input pattern` in a service if service already running. Shared data isn't shared pattern ! Can change output not input(like: My_db_answer.decode(my_encoding_system)). are you walking on the roads dangerous. **A system does not allow the achievement of infinite loop !**

Comment: @user, Yes, because SO outputs them in utf-8 encoding. Here's a header: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky Interesting point, but I'm getting `Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8D\x97' for column 'caption' at row 1`. Notice they're all 4 bytes: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: 4 bytes is not a problem -  UTF-8 is a variable length encoding, it has codes from 1 to 6 bytes length.  It's not a UTF-8 issue, it's an issue of tools incapable to handle it correctly. Proof is below.  Here're symbols:   as they are on screen. Here's their hexdump from database/files/etc: `f0 9f 98 8d f0 9f 98 82  f0 9f 99 88 f0 9f 92 81`. If you do not trust me - just open [my telegram bot](https://telegram.me/dj-tg-alpha-bot) and send it 2 commands: /start and /list.

Answer (score -2):

It's neither issue of Django nor Mysql, it's a Windows issue. Unfortunately it supports unicode not the best way.

I started playing with Django 0.9 at year 2004 on Windows XP. From time to time I was getting strange bugs. Later I moved to Cygwin and some of them disappeared, but some remained. Problem is in encodings mechanism built in Windows. Only move to Linux and then Mac helped me to avoid such "Geizenbugs".

So you are quite right:

> When I start my script on Mac or Linux, it works fine, but on Windows, I get [error].

Best option - switch to Mac or Linux. If you do not want to move completely to *nix, you may use you Windows environment and put Django and Mysql to virtual env like Vagrant or Docker.

I've tested you emojis on my pet project.

Here's django admin interface:

[image]

And here's telegram bot:

[image]

All is OK.

I use:

- heroku hosting (linux)
- PostgreSQL (but it doesn't depend on DB)
- Python 3.5.2
- all works in UTF-8 encoding.